# Movie from the 90s where the superhero gets the strength from the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, movie, super-hero

I have been looking for a movie that I watched around 25 years ago. The protagonist was a normal person who happened to pick up a watch/ring from an alien/god. Each time he touched it and said something like "galaxy, please give me your strength", the watch/ring would give him a supersuit with cape, and he could fly. He wasn't afraid of bullets either, but when the bad guy tried to attack him with poisonous smoke and ultrasound, he was vulnerable to either of them (I couldn't remember which one). The bad guys seemed to be normal people with a lot of modern weapons.

At the end of the movie, he defeated the bad guys, won the girl (of course) and threw the watch/ring away. His useless friend then tried to look for it.

The movie was dubbed in my mother tongue when I watched it, so the phrase "galaxy etc" might be wrong.

The movie might be incomparable to the Marvel's ones, but it left me with so much impression since I watched it when I were a child. I had to go very far to watch it, since at that time having a TV was just like having a Tesla Model S at the current time (I'm from a third-word country, and our government is communism)

---

## Update

All actors are white people. The supersuite of the protagonist was very simple, just like the one of superman without the "S" symbol, but it also had a mask.

The bad guys lived in a technically advanced base. At the end of the movie, the protagonist attacked the base to save the girl. They shot him, but the bullets couldn't hurt him. They then tried with poisonous smoke, and then with ultrasound, which eventually made him fainted. I couldn't remember how he recovered, perhaps the girl, being captured at the base at that time, helped him, but I'm not sure. He also had a sidekick, who was just a normal person, and as I've mentioned he tried to look for the watch after the protagonist had thrown it away. I believe this was more of a watch than a ring, one needed to circle it around the wrist before saying the phrase.

I can't remember the language since I watched it when I was very small and did not know any foreign language. But the movie was very likely from the US.

---

## Update 2

The title of the movie in my mother tongue, if translated word by word to English, is "the ultrasound man". I'm not sure if the title in my mother tongue is correct.

When attacking the base, the superhero needed to walk through a long hallway where all the walls were white, the poisonous smoke came out from the wall. The leader of the bad guys were in the control room to watch the superhero as he were attacking the base. He controlled the smoke, ultrasound from there by clicking some buttons. The girl was in the control room with him.

Comment: If you say "watch/ring", you mean a bracelet?

Comment: @MrLister yes, something like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Supersonic Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079971/)

It was released in 1979 in France and various other countries in 1980 and 1981, however, user review from the IMDb page sounds like this could be the movie you are looking for.

> Superhero Kronos , an alien, called "Supersonic Man," (a bodybuilder
>   and former Tarzan , Richard Yesteran) is sent to Earth to decide the
>   fate of mankind and thwart the schemes of evil men who would destroy
>   the galaxy itself with their weapons from a distant galaxy .
>   Supersonic is also given a human identity , Paul (Michael Coby or
>   Antonio Cantafora) , a journalist who can change back to superhero by
>   activating a watch device . But a nutty mad doctor named Gulik
>   (Cameron Mitchell), supported by his hoodlums (Frank Braña, Luis
>   Barboo), has evil plans , as he wants to rule the planet and abduct
>   Patricia (Diana Polakov) , an eminent scientific (Jose Maria
>   Caffarel)'s daughter and Supersonic's love interest . At the end our
>   hero , Supersonic , enters the underground lair of the villain and has
>   to pass through some corridors where he is shot, frozen, and burnt.

Comment: Mad Scientist's Beautiful Daughter.